# Getting my ip adress provided by vpn without visiting any page

Tags: python, selenium, vb6, ip

I use vpn and connect to a website with selenium.
I can see my ip provided from vpn by going to http://ipconfig.io/ip.
My question is, when i use vpn https://ipinfo.io/ip website gives my ip which i use with vpn.
Can i do the same thing using either with vb6 or python? Or with selenium?

Comment: Can I do this without even going to websites like [link](http://ipconfig.io/ip) or [link](http://checkip.dyndns.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can "download" the page from http://ipconfig.io/ip in VB6 and parse the address from the raw html. Here is a [`pvGetExternalIP` function](https://github.com/wqweto/VbAsyncSocket/blob/master/test/Basic/Form1.frm#L652-L674) that does this from the original http://checkip.dyndns.org as provided from Dyn.

```
Private Function pvGetExternalIP() As String
    Dim sResponse     As String
    
    With New cAsyncSocket
        .SyncConnect "checkip.dyndns.org", 80
        .SyncSendText "GET / HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Host: checkip.dyndns.org" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Do
            sResponse = sResponse & .SyncReceiveText()
            If InStr(sResponse, vbCrLf & vbCrLf) > 0 Then
                With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
                    .Pattern = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
                    sResponse = .Execute(sResponse).Item(0)
                End With
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End With
    If sResponse Like "*.*.*.*" Then
        pvGetExternalIP = sResponse
    Else
        pvGetExternalIP = "127.0.0.1"
    End If
End Function
```

This uses raw http request and parses the raw http response.